# axios POST get 400

Tags: axios

This is driving me crazy!
Exactly the same POST request works fine in Insomina per screenshot below:
[image]

The only header Insomina has is: `Content-Type: application/json`.

Now, the same request in code (**I even copied the code generated from Insomnia for axios**) via axios in Typescript:

```
  const saveReqConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'THE SAME URL USED IN Insomina',
          timeout: 3000,
          data: {
            name: `TestName`,
            uri: `TestURI`,
            statusCode: '200',
            simulatedLatency: '0',
            contentType: "application/json",
            tags: '',
            response: 'testing...',
            type: 'VA',
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        }
        const normalAxios = axios.create();
        const test = await normalAxios.request(saveReqConfig);
```

Don't understand why I am getting `AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400` from code but the same request works fine in Insomina.

Comment: `The only header Insomina has is: Content-Type: application/json.` that's your answer right there. Add that header.

Comment: Should you not pass your config to the ```.create()```. And then pass the url and body to the instance you create? Do you need to use ```.create()``` instead of just ```axios.post```? Do you need the factory?

Comment: @DeepakKamat added the header and still the same error. Question edited too.

Comment: @TumoMasire. tried `axios.post()` and got the same error. So trying to post in the lengthy style.

Comment: Well I gave a fuller example. It may not help you, but may help others.

Comment: Do you get additional information in your Browser Dev tools? Did you compare request and response headers?

Comment: @Uwe this is a server side call; no browser is involved.

Comment: @dragonfly02 get the errors like explained in https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors and maybe try and could you elaborate on what environment your are running? - Could you Try to set a origin header?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not set the headers correctly or you may not have setup the .create() properly.

Something like this:

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  url: '/post',
  baseURL: 'https://httpbin.org',
  method: 'POST',
  timeout: 1000, 
  headers: {
  Content-Type: 'application/json' // <- set your headers
 }
});

let res = await instance.request({ // <- pass the data here
  data: { // This should be whatever you want to post to this url. I just copied what you had.
            name: `TestName`,
            uri: `TestURI`,
            statusCode: '200',
            simulatedLatency: '0',
            tags: '',
            response: 'testing...',
            type: 'VA',
          }
});
```

Are you sure you need to use the .create() factory? The normal post like this might suite your needs better?

```js
const data= { title: 'Axios POST Request Example' };
const headers = { 
    Content-Type: 'application/json'
};

axios.post('url', data, { headers }).then(response => console.log(response.data.title);
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort but we send all our http requests via axios in the form of `axiosInstance.request(reqConfig)`  where `reqConfig` contains all details of the request including both data and headers for a post request.

Comment: Noted. Did you see the part of having the ```baseURL```, then the ```url``` for what comes after your domain or base url?

Comment: `baseURL` is all what it needs.

Comment: Well I hope you maybe tried the ```baseURL``` and ```url```. Do you have access to the logs from the API? If what you are saying is correct, then this is indeed a very strange error. Could you post the body of the error response?

Comment: Yes I tried `url` and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Posting here in case it helps someone.
It turned out that I couldn't post the request programmatically is because of lack of a TLS certificate. I didn't know that Insomnia has the option to disable the TLS and that's why it works in Insomnia.
To disable TLS (Do NOT do this in production!) from node with axios, create an instance of `axios` with a https agent setting rejectedUnauthorized to false e.g.

```
const instance = axios.create({
   httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
      rejectedUnauthorized: false
   })
});


Also, set the environment variable as:
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```